# Auto increment value get set to ' 18446744073709551615 ' with multiple load data infile

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

I am facing one problem with one of my project.I have a inventory upload which import data from csv to a innodb table. What happened here is with a multiple load data command (i suppose) the auto increment value get sets to 18446744073709551615 and not letting other insert to work. It was working fine before. I am not sure if the large amount of data in the table creates this issue or not.

Details of the table is as follows

Software version: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log - (Ubuntu)

largest insert id used : 17455787099

number of rows in the table : 23887371

some variables realted to this are as follows

auto increment increment 1
auto increment offset 1
autocommit ON
automatic sp privileges ON
innodb autoextend increment 8
innodb autoinc lock mode 1
sql auto is null OFF Documentation

i have removed the delete queries from the table. But still the autoincriment is out of sync

any help is much appreciated

thanks

Nithin

Comment: Import without `AUTO_INCREMENT`, set it after you are done.

Comment: If the auto-inc field is of type `INTEGER`, it can only handle numbers so large.. I don't remember exactly but it can be found on this site. Try changing it to `BIGINT` **Integer max val = 4,294,967,295**

Comment: @BartFriederichs i am importing with out auto increment

Comment: @DevlshOne currently i am using unsigned bigint

Comment: Is your auto increment field referenced in other tables?

Comment: You've omitted what I'd consider the most relevant piece of info: does the incoming dataset contain a row where the column is `18446744073709551615` or greater?

Comment: @Mihai no auto increment is not referenced in other table

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario the incoming data set does not contain any day data greater  or equal to 18446744073709551615

Comment: Oh,and also post that multiple load command.

Answer (score 2):

> the auto increment value get sets to 18446744073709551615-largest
>   insert id used : 17455787099

This is a bit confusing.

Try resetting the auto increment value before loading new files:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

**EDIT:**

Create a new identical table :

```
CREATE TABLE tableName LIKE oldtableName;
```

Copy all rows to the new table, remember to not select the auto_incrementing id.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (field2, field3, field4)
SELECT field2, field3, field4 FROM oldtableName ORDER BY oldtableName.id;
DROP oldtableName;
RENAME tableName oldtableName;
```

This will take a while(hours..or more).

**EDIT2**

If your id column is not referenced by anything

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP id

ALTER TABLE tableName ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id), AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
 the auto increment value get sets to 18446744073709551615-largest insert id used : 17455787099
auto increment shown in table status is 18446744073709551615

I have already tried edit2 you specified .But the issue occurred again.
Regarding
    ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
it is taking a lot of time for this query to execute it